# Check if an X509 certificate has been revoked or not?

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate

The code below is what I currently have. It gets a certificate from a server, and checks for validity. However, I would like to also know how I can add a check to this to see if it has been revoked? (I know if I get it, and check it instantly, it wont be revoked, but I will be modifying this after we come to a solution, in order to check it at a later time.) I had asked a similar question initially, and have deleted it due to it being written when I had no idea what I wanted to do. Thanks in advance!

```
protected boolean testCert() throws Exception
{
    // Get the current environment.

    Environment myTestEnvironment = Environment.valueOf(env);
    URL verificationUrl =  environmentService.getProfile(myTestEnvironment).getConnectUrl();
    boolean result = false;

    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) verificationUrl.openConnection();
    conn.connect();

    Certificate[] certs = conn.getServerCertificates();

    // This is set in order to have a readable output for debugging.
    this.testURL = verificationUrl.toString().replaceFirst("^(https://www\\.|https://|www\\.)","");

    for (Certificate cert : certs) {
        if (cert instanceof X509Certificate) {
            try {
                ((X509Certificate) cert).checkValidity();
                result = true;
            } catch (CertificateExpiredException cee) {
                result = false;}
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this link from @CommonWare will be helpful for you https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/18/more-android-revoked-ssl-certificates.html

Comment: This is all defined in the [JDK Guide to Security documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html#AppC).

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing I seem to try based on that document seems to work, I had been working with the security document for a day before I even posted here.